# using Bootstrap SASS mixins for browser support

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, mixins

I have used 
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s; 
and 
-moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;

in my CSS with transitions to support older browsers.

I am currently working on a bootstrap project with lots of transitions. I have been looking into MIXINS and was wondering if it is possible using something like this

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_vendor-prefixes.scss

so that all of my transitions have those tags aswell.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Just use an autoprefixer and you can forget about vendor prefixes :-)

Comment: i'm not sure I understand what you mean. What would this look like?

Comment: Well depending on your OS and you setup. It could be done using compass, node, ruby and sass gem. Show us what you got, your project setup; tell us the details.